# How to change the listening port on IIS 7 web application?

Tags: iis7, iis

I have an apache running on port 80, I want to move my Web Applications to *:8080 But I don't remember how. I've seen [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/72620/how-to-change-listening-port-on-webbserver-iis-7) but **Edit Bindings** isn't in my options list. Not even in **Basic Settings** nor in **Advanced Settings**.

Heres An image of What I've got.

[image: IIS - Left Panel Options]

Comment: this actually inspired me to give a try to IIS in a controlled environment: +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the image you can clearly see

`Server/Sites/Default Web Site/A Web Application`

In order to bring to the UI the binding option, **Default Web Site** should be selected and not *A Web Application*.

You have to change the binding of the whole website, which seems correct. (It has no *short term* sense that you have two ports for the same webApp)

Answer (score 5):

From [How to change the TCP port for IIS services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149605)

1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
2. Select the Web site that you wish to configure.
3. In the Action pane, click Bindings.
4. Click Add to add a new site binding, or click Edit to change an existing binding.
5. Click OK to apply the changes.

Comment: But, as you can see there isn't any Bindings selection on the website which port I want to change. I know that that's how I'm supposed to do it I've done it before...(once or twice) but I just don't see that option. What Am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

For an hour I searched for the solution and it was only the firewall. I suspended it and was then able to log in to Vault in Inventor. I could log in to Vault Explorer no problem, just not from Inventor. Anyway stopping my firewall for a moment was the trick.

Answer (score 0):

IIS might not be installed properly.

From [this thread](http://forums.iis.net/t/1155799.aspx)...

> - Remove both IIS and Windows Process Activation Service
> - Click Programs    and Features in Control Panel
> - Click "Turn Windows Features on or off"
> - Under Features summary, click "Add Features"
> - Now expand out  ".NET Framework 3.0 Features) "
> - click "WCF Activation"
> - It will    automatically ask you if you want to add the required file service
>     roles
> - say "yes"
> - click next select the roles you want.
> - The roles will install, and you will now have the normal IP addresss, port, host
>     name, etc. show up

Comment: That was already done

Answer (score -2):

For Windows 7 or 8, search For IIS manager then in left pane select default website and select edit the bindings. Choose the port which you want to set.